# Make INDEX return a row n times

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm almost certain this question has been asked before but I couldn't find the answer and have - to be perfectly honest - not the slightest idea what to even call the following problem:

In an excel table I want a sort of false counter whith every number appearing n times.

It will be nested inside a bigger Index formula to basically extract every column n times, to make it look like this

[image]

By nesting INT into MOD I managed to get alternating counts:
`=MOD(INT(ROW())/2;1)` results in the alternating values of `0.5` and `0`

However this doesn't seem to lead to a solution for my original problem. So anyone with a name for the functionality I'm looking for or a solution for it has my gratitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were close:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Value],INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/2)+1)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! Works perfectly. Out of cuiosity: why did you reference cell ZZ1? With the ROW function it shouldn't make a difference whether the cell is empty or not, right?

Comment: You want to specify the start is row 1 if you use `ROW()` without the range it will use the row in which it is placed.  That is not accurate enough for this.  I use ZZ1 just so I know it is a counter only and not an actual reference to data.

Comment: Fair enough, I meant why not use `ROW($A1)` instead. But I'll keep that in mind as a nice way to keep long formulas a little more clear :D

Answer (score 1):

Found another (way more complicated) way to do this:

`=INDEX(Table1[Value],INT((ROW()-ROW([Formula])+2)/2))`